# Silverlight unit testing (using NUnit)

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, continuous-integration, silverlight-4.0

I'm using NUnit for testing back-end. Unit tests are being executed while building (I'm using TeamCity for continuous building).

Now I hove to test front-end (Silverlight 4.0). Because the tests are being executed while building, I have to simulate browser (TypeMock - is not free, isn't it?) could I use NUnit.Mocks somehow?. How to use NUnit for Silverlight testing? I've found [WHITE](http://white.codeplex.com/) framework could it help?

Any other advises about software/frameworks to use for Silverlight unit testing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out StatLight...

*"StatLight is a tool developed for automating the setup, running, and gathering results of Silverlight unit tests. StatLight helps to speed up the feedback cycles while practicing  TDD/BDD/(insert your test style here) during Silverlight development."*

http://statlight.net/

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, here is an nUnit port for Silverlight:

http://greenicicleblog.com/2010/04/27/nunit-for-silverlight-updated/